# How to access data in partialview loaded using Ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm currently building a website where I have to update two separate targets from a single `Ajax.BeginForm`. I got it working by using an additional container to container the two separate targets. As in:

1. Original Form

   ```
   @model Mod1
   @using (Ajax.BeginForm("LoadData", new AjaxOptions{UpdateTargetID = "Div1"}))
   {
     <select id="sel1" name="sel1" onchange="$(this.form).submit">
       // ...
     </select>
   }
   @using (Ajax.BeginForm("ProcessData", new AjaxOptions{UpdateTargetID = "Div2"}))
   {
     <div id="Div1"></div>
       // ...
     <input type="submit" value="GO!" />
   }
   ```
2. Code File

   ```
   public ActionResult LoadData(int sel1)
   {
     // loading data from database
     return PartialView(mod1);
   }
   ```
3. Partial View

   ```
   @model Mod2
   <select id="sel2" name="sel2">
     @foreach (var item in Model.SelectItems)
     {
       <option value="@item.Value">@item.Text</option>
     }
   </select>

   @foreach (var item in Model.CheckBoxItems)
   {
     <label>@item.Text<input type="checkbox" id="chk1" name="chk1" value="@item.Value"></label>
   }
   ```

For the processing method, I have tried:

```
    public ProcessData(Mod1 mod1, string[] chk1, int sel2)
```

However I am unable to retrieve the values for either chk1 or sel2 upon form submission. examination of chk1 and sel2 in Debug mode, chk1 is null while sel2 is 0 (no such value in the select options). Can anyone please offer some insight into the reason for this and also how I can go about solving it. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you can do what you want y having two submit buttons on the same form, each calling a separate action method. That way each submit button will have access to all the fields in the form. For a detailed explanation of how you can do that see my answer here:

[How to use ajax link instead of submit button for form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18056797/how-to-use-ajax-link-instead-of-submit-button-for-form)

**Edit**

In response to comment: the action method LoadData should return a partial view that contains the other two controls and have the whole begin form included in it:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("LoadData", new AjaxOptions{
                                                UpdateTargetID = "Div1",
                                                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
                                                  })) 
{
    <select id="sel1" name="sel1" onchange="$(this.form).submit">
    // ...
    </select>
}
<div id="Div1">
</div>
<div id="Div2">
</div>
```

Move this to another partial view:

```
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("ProcessData", new AjaxOptions{UpdateTargetID = "Div2"}))
    {

        // ...
        <input type="submit" value="GO!" />
    }
```

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted. My intention is that by selecting a value from a DropDownList. Another DropDownList and CheckBoxes enclosed in a div is updated with values. The user will select/ check the options in the div subsequently and submit the form. However I'm unable to access the submitted value in either fields as they are 0 (for int field) and null (for string[] field).

Comment: I'm still getting a null reference for the checkboxes when submitting the form. Using either int[] or string[] doesn't not solve the situation either...