# MVC submit from a div pop up

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

I am fairly new to MVC development.

I have a controller called "Usercontroller" to manage SignIn, Forgot password and registration. 
I have added HttpGet, HttpPost methods to SignIn. HttpPost SignIn method is an overload of the SignIn function with "Model.User".
I have a "Forgot Password" method as well. (Send the email).

Forgot Password is a div pop up, which has a "Send Link" functionality.
If I click on "Send Link", it will also hit the "SignIn" method in the user controller. 
Need to identify this and call "Forgot Password" method. How can I do this? Or is there a better way to implement forgot password?

Comment: Can you please put the "Forgot password" screenshot (Or HTML code) here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to know, which button has been pressed, following code gives you the solution to this problem:

Give the buttons the same name

**View:**

```
 <input type="submit" id="btn1" name="btnSubmit" value="Login" />
 <input type="submit" id="btn2" name="btnSubmit" value="Forgot Password" />
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ReturnFunction(Model model, string btnSubmit)
{
  switch (btnSubmit) {
    case "Login":
      //Code for checking credentials here
      break;
    case "Forgot Password":
     //Code retrieving password here
      break;
  }
```

The switch statement handles the button values, so you can tell which button has been clicked.

Answer (score 1):

make a private method in `UserController` called `AuthenticateUser()`

Then logIn and ForgotPassword Actions will call `AuthenticateUser()` before performing the rest of their logic

Comment: How can I distinguish whether this call is coming from the "Login Submit" or "Forgot Password Submit"?

Comment: @Dhanuka777 Look at my answer, for distinguishing which button has been clicked.

Comment: @Dhanuka777 - That answer from Max will work ,  I thought you were sending LogIn button to a LogIn Action, and Forgot Password button to ForgotPasswordAction ,  keeping these action seperate , but sharing the same authentication function.  That's the way I would do it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you keep getting redirected to the SignIn() action when hitting your '/User/ForgotPassword' url, then most likely the ForgotPassword action is requesting authentication, and as the user isn't authenticated, it redirects them to the login page.

Try adding the following into your web.config:

```
<location path="User/ForgotPassword">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

You can put this just below the end tag of the 'system.web' node, for e.g.:

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name="YourCookieName" loginUrl="/User/SignIn" path="/" domain="" timeout="40320" slidingExpiration="true"/>
  </authentication>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
  </authorization>

  <!-- the rest of your system.web config in here -->
</system.web>

<location path="User/ForgotPassword">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Although, this is just a guess at what your issue may be.

Answer (score 1):

We have adopted a solution for all pages that require to have multiple submit buttons per form which would be applicable in your case (have used it in login as well as other senarios). I have outlined it along with a code example here:

[How to use ajax link instead of submit button for form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18056797/how-to-use-ajax-link-instead-of-submit-button-for-form/18057461#18057461)

In your case since you are using the popup you may have to use javascript to have the popup button call a hidden submit button included in the original form depending on how you open your dialog.