# Trigger POST method by different buttons which are present in the same page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC 4 in my application, I am trying to call post methods by clicking on the buttons.

I have included 3 buttons in a page[Index.cshtml], like `"Submit" | "Update" | "Delete"` when i click on submit button it should trigger to `Insert[POST]` method and same thing should be happen to Delete. when i click on Delete button it should trigger to `Delete[POST]` method. but every time it is triggering to `Index[Post]` method?

Please help me some!!

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer I have given to a similar question. It should help with what you want:

[How to use ajax link instead of submit button for form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18056797/how-to-use-ajax-link-instead-of-submit-button-for-form/18057461#18057461)

Comment: is it possible to achieve my this task without using Ajax ?

Comment: Just use html.BeginForm instead of Ajax.BeginForm